# How to fix the join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Im making a new program and I am stuck with this join. I get an error saying Type inference failed in the call to 'join'

```
var fill = from Projekt in sqlObj.Projekts
                   join s in sqlObj.Status on Projekt.StatusID equals s.StatusDescription
                   where Projekt.StatusID !=6
                   select new
                   {
                       Projekt.StatusID,
                       Projekt.ProjektName,
                       Projekt.Projekt_User,
                       s.StatusDescription
                   };
        OnGoingProjekts.ItemsSource = fill.ToList();
```

I expect to get the name of the status out in my Datagrid. Not the id itself.

Comment: "i expect to get the name of the status " then you should incorporate it in the select statement. Or is `s.StatusDescription` meant to be the name?

Comment: You want StatusID to join on StatusDescription?  Usually the join is the same type like ID, or name, or description.

Comment: What type is _StatusID_? And what type is _StatusDEscription_?

Comment: first issue, as mentioned by @jdweng, i presume the `StatusId` property type is int and the `StatusDescription` is string, they cannot be used in join. After addressing this, you should add it in the `select` statement `Projekt` or `s.Name` as mentioned by @Mong Zhu

Comment: StatusID is an INT and StatusDescription is nvarchat(max).

Comment: @Wind_dk Then you can't join these two columns. This wouldn't word in plain sql either.

Comment: Never assume that an ID is an integer because half the time you will be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to guess because I don't have all the information but it looks like you try to join on two different type of fields.

Instead try to join the status on the ID.

```
var fill = from Projekt in sqlObj.Projekts
                   join s in sqlObj.Status on Projekt.StatusID equals s.Id
                   where Projekt.StatusID !=6
                   select new
                   {
                       Projekt.StatusID,
                       Projekt.ProjektName,
                       Projekt.Projekt_User,
                       s.StatusDescription
                   };
        OnGoingProjekts.ItemsSource = fill.ToList();
```